# skmaps how can i zoom in on current position in navigation

Tags: ios, skmaps

I'am using Navigation on map and i want to center on my position with a zoom in when i make zoom out(Screen Shot), how can i do this?

This is how i did but it doesn't work :

```
-(IBAction)centrerAction:(id)sender
```

{

```
[self.skMap animateToLocation:userLocation.coordinate withDuration:0];
[self.skMap animateToZoomLevel:19];
```

}

Thanks for Help.

[image]

Comment: In free drive/navigation the positioner icon is always centred on the map after zoom in or zoom out (Routing & Navigation -> Calculate route -> Start navigation -> zoom in/out). Can you add more details- what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I tried that too without success. You can also use:

```
SKCoordinateRegion currentLocationRegion;
currentLocationRegion.center = [[SKPositionerService sharedInstance]currentCoordinate];
currentLocationRegion.zoomLevel = 19;

[self.skMap setVisibleRegion:currentLocationRegion];
```